# PromQL - Rename Output metrics label

Tags: prometheus, promql

If I query something like this :-

```
requests_total{app='myApp', status='200'}
```

I get

```
requests_total{app='myApp', status='200', uri='/blahblah', otherLabels='othervalues'}  50
```

In the output, is it possible to rename labels, for example: "app" to "service", "status" to "responseCode" ?

I have no control over input metrics, but there is another system which expects metrics to follow a specific naming convention.

Answer (score 2):

It is possible to rename labels with [label_replace](https://docs.victoriametrics.com/MetricsQL.html#label_replace) function. For example, the following query adds `service` label with the value of the original `app` label:

```
label_replace(
  requests_total{app='myApp', status='200'},
  "service",
  "$1",
  "app",
  "(.+)"
)
```

Note that the query doesn't remove the original `app` label from matching time series. If you need removing the original `app` label, then use the following query:

```
label_replace(
  label_replace(
    requests_total{app='myApp', status='200'},
    "service",
    "$1",
    "app",
    "(.+)"
  ),
  "app",
  "",
  "app",
  "(.+)"
)
```

The outer `label_replace()` substitutes the `app` label with an empty value, so the label is removed from the resulting time series.

If you need subsituting multiple labels, then you need to write multiple nested `label_replace()` function calls. For example, the following query copies `app` label into `service` and `status` label into `responseCode`:

```
label_replace(
  label_replace(
    requests_total{app='myApp', status='200'},
    "service",
    "$1",
    "app",
    "(.+)"
  ),
  "responseCode",
  "$1",
  "status",
  "(.+)"
)
```

P.S. There is an alternative Prometheus-like solution I work on, which provides easier to use function for this particular case. The solution is named VictoriaMetrics. It provides [label_move](https://docs.victoriametrics.com/MetricsQL.html#label_move) function for exactly this case. For example, the following [MetricsQL](https://docs.victoriametrics.com/MetricsQL.html) query renames `app` into `service` and `status` into `responseCode`:

```
label_move(
  requests_total{app='myApp', status='200'},
  "app", "service",
  "status", "responseCode",
)
```